# Possible infinite loop on math equation?

Tags: math, simulation, montecarlo

I have the following problem, and am having trouble understanding part of the equation:

Monte Carlo methods to estimate an integral is basically, take a lot of random samples and determined a weighted average. For example, the integral of f(x) can be estimated from N independent random samples x<sub>r</sub> by

[alt text http://www.goftam.com/images/area.gif](http://www.goftam.com/images/area.gif)

for a uniform probability distribution of xr in the range [x1, x2]. Since each
function evaluation f(xr) is independent, it is easy to distribute this work
over a set of processes.

What I don't understand is what f(x<sub>r</sub>) is supposed to do? Does it feed back into the same equation? Wouldn't that be an infinite loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your goal is to compute the integral of `f` from `x1` to `x2`.  For example, you may wish to compute the integral of `sin(x)` from `0` to `pi`.

Using Monte Carlo integration, you can approximate this by sampling random points in the interval `[x1,x2]` and evaluating `f` at those points.  Perhaps you'd like to call this `MonteCarloIntegrate( f, x1, x2 )`.

So no, `MonteCarloIntegrate` does not "feed back" into itself.  It calls a function `f`, the function you are trying to numerically integrate, e.g. `sin`.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: and +1 for you. =)

Answer (score 11):

It should say f(x<sub>i</sub>)

f() is the function we are trying to integrate via the numerical monte carlo method, which estimates an integral (and its error) by evaluating randomly choosen points from the integration region.

[Ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration).

Comment: I'd rather change the summation index to r, and the limits of integration to a and b. That way there is no confusion about the x_i's.

Comment: x_i is fairly standard notation.

Comment: It's bad notation either way, because x1 and x2 are the limits of your integral.  You want the xi or xr, whichever you prefer, to be randomly distributed in [x1,x2].

Comment: I disagree that it's bad notation. Like many things in Mathematics there are accepted forms that are used. To me x_i seems very natural

Comment: Re the notation: xi by itself is fine notation, and obviously accepted throughout math.  The summation is over i from 1 to N, which means it also includes i=1 and i=2.  That means that part of your sum is f(x1) and f(x2), which are the value of your function at the endpoints.  You may not want this.

Comment: Should be x_r_i since x_1 and x_2 are the endpoints of integration.

Comment: Re the downvote: I was wavering back and forth about whether or not I should -1. The reason I did not want to is you're clearly trying to be helpful and the -1 is "not right". However, your original answer (that it should be f(xi)) did not answer the question, yet got 2 votes somehow.

Comment: Continuing: then, within the five minutes, you edited to include an answer to the actual question (but no one can tell that). I thought this was symptomatic of the "fastest gun in the west problem", and I decided to balance that with a -1.  As I said, I've taken it away, but I hope you understand.

Comment: @A. Rex: I'm not sure what you mean? I did edit a few times, but I'm a lousy typist. sorry for any consusion

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: The use of x_i is wrong here since the endpoints are labeled as x_1 and x_2. Thus, a different notation for the randomly chosen points is needed.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: In short, here's the sequence of events: 1. You answer saying it should be x_i, which doesn't remotely answer the question. 2. I actually answer the question. 3. You *edit* your answer to actually answer the question. 4. You get upvoted a *lot*.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: It's true.  By the way, please don't get me wrong: I think you're a great SO user.  No hard feelings.  =)

Comment: @A Rex & Mitch Wheat: It's heartening to see you two come to an amicable conclusion on this. It gives me hope for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `f(x_r)` by `f(x_r_i)` (read: f evaluated at `x` sub `r` sub `i`). The `r_i` are chosen uniformly at random from the interval `[x_1, x_2]`.

The point is this: the area under `f` on `[x_1, x_2]` is equal to `(x_2 - x_1)` times the average of `f` on the interval `[x_1, x_2]`. That is

```
A = (x_2 - x_1) * [(1 / (x_2 - x_1)) * int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x)\, dx]
```

The portion in square brackets is the average of `f` on `[x_1, x_2]` which we will denote `avg(f)`. How can we estimate the average of `f`? By sampling it at `N` random points and taking the average value of `f` evaluated at those random points. To wit:

```
avg(f) ~ (1 / N) * sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_r_i)
```

where `x_r_1, x_r_2, ..., x_r_N` are points chosen uniformly at random from [x_1, x_2].

Then

```
A = (x_2 - x_1) * avg(f) ~ (x_2 - x_1) * (1 / N) * sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_r_i).
```

Here is another way to think about this equation: the area under `f` on the interval `[x_1, x_2]` is the same as the area of a rectangle with length `(x_2 - x_1)` and height equal to the average height of `f`. The average height of `f` is approximately

```
(1 / N) * sum_{i=1}^{N} f(x_r_i)
```

which is value that we produced previously.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's x<sub>i</sub> or x<sub>r</sub> is irrelevant - it's the random number that we're feeding into function f().

I'm more likely to write the function (aside from formatting) as follows:

(x<sub>2</sub>-x<sub>1</sub>) * sum(f(x<sub>i</sub>))/N

That way, we can see that we're taking the average of N samples of f(x) to get an average height of the function, then multiplying by the width (x2-x1).

Because, after all, integration is just calculating area under the curve.  (Nice pictures at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/Hbase/integ.html#c4.

Answer (score 0):

x_r is a random value from the integral's range.

Substituting Random(x_1, x_2) for x_r would give an equivalent equation.